# Type Checking failed when using Dependent Pair

Tags: idris, dependent-type

I write down this:

```
data IsTag : String -> Type where
    NumIsTag : IsTag "num"
    StrIsTag : IsTag "str"

arr1 : List (tag : String ** (IsTag tag, (case tag of "num" => Int; "str" => String)))
arr1 = [("num" ** (NumIsTag, 1)), ("str" ** (StrIsTag, "hello"))]
```

And get the following wield error message:

```
When checking right hand side of arr1 with expected type
        List (tag : String **
              (IsTag tag, case tag of   "num" => Int "str" => String))

When checking argument b to constructor Builtins.MkPair:
        case "num" of
          "num" => Int
          "str" => String is not a numeric type
```

But I can't understand, Why `case "num" of "num" => Int; "str" => String` is not a numeric type?  isn't it equals to `Int` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not, because Idris does not reduce partial (non-total) functions during type-checking.

If you have a good default type for the cases when your string is not equal to `"num"` / `"str"` then you can have something like this:

```
total
tagToType : String -> Type
tagToType "num" = Int
tagToType "str" = String
tagToType _ = ?defaultType

arr1 : List (tag : String ** (IsTag tag, tagToType tag))
arr1 = [("num" ** (NumIsTag, 1)), ("str" ** (StrIsTag, "hello"))]
```

---

Another option is to define it like so:

```
total
tagToType : IsTag s -> Type
tagToType NumIsTag = Int
tagToType StrIsTag = String

arr1 : List (tag : String ** istag : IsTag tag ** tagToType istag)
arr1 = [("num" ** NumIsTag ** 1), ("str" ** StrIsTag ** "hello")]
```

Comment: But I have told Idris that "str" is a tag, and proved it. what should I do to make Idris believe that tag must be a tag?

Comment: what if I don't need a defaultType, and want to prove to idris that tag must be one of "num" and "str" ?

Comment: @luochen1990 I updated the answer. Is this kind of solution what you are looking for?

Comment: thank you, but what if I want to hide the redundant part?

Comment: I think you answered my original question, and I should not edit it to another one, I will open a new question for that one, thank you! @Anton Trunov

Comment: You can inline: `tagToType` into `arr1`'s type -- `List (tag : String ** istag : IsTag tag ** case istag of NumIsTag => Int; StrIsTag => String)`. If this is what you mean by "redundant".

Comment: Thanks, can you have a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170626/how-to-put-things-with-different-type-into-a-list-tagged-by-string