# How to put things with different type into a list, tagged by string?

Tags: idris, dependent-type

I'm trying to put things with different type into a list, tagged by string.

What I want is something like that:

```
arr1 : ?what_should_that_be
arr1 = [("num" ** 1), ("str" ** "hello")]
```

So I tried to prove that what I given as a tag is actually a valid tag (by providing a proof of `IsTag tag`), but it seems that the compiler didn't get it, so what should I do now?

```
data IsTag : String -> Type where
    NumIsTag : IsTag "num"
    StrIsTag : IsTag "str"

total
typeOf : (tag : String) -> {auto prf: IsTag tag} -> Type
typeOf _ {prf = NumIsTag} = Int
typeOf _ {prf = StrIsTag} = String

arr1 : List (tag : String ** typeOf tag)
arr1 = [("num" ** 1), ("str" ** "hello")]
```

It ends up with the following error message:

```
When checking type of Main.arr1:
When checking argument prf to Main.typeOf:
        Can't find a value of type
                IsTag tag
```

I think this error message implies that `arr1` has a wrong type, but what type should it have?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to convince Idris the following is a valid type:

```
List (tag : String ** typeOf tag)
```

The `typeOf` function has two parameters (one of which is supposed to be inferable by Idris on its own). Now, let's pretend for a moment that the second parameter is explicit. How would you write `typeOf` application by hand?

```
List (tag : String ** typeOf tag <proof>)
```

But at this point all you know about `tag` is that it is a `String` so you cannot provide that proof -- there is just not enough information available.

Comment: But, at this morment, what I want to do is just define arr1, which is a const list, it can be proved to be valid with no doubt, what should I do here so that I can define arr1?

Comment: `arr1` can't make sense if its type does not make sense to begin with. `typeOf tag` can only make sense if Idris can build a proof that `IsTag tag` using `auto` which it can't because `tag` could be anything in the expression `(tag : String ** typeOf tag)`.

Answer (score 1):

I find that works:

```
data IsTag : String -> Type where
    NumIsTag : IsTag "num"
    StrIsTag : IsTag "str"

total
typeOf : (tag : String) -> Type
typeOf "num" = Int
typeOf "str" = String
typeOf _ = Void

arr1 : List (tag : String ** typeOf tag)
arr1 = [("num" ** 1), ("str" ** "hello")]
```

Instead of trying to prove that the tag is valid, I use `Void` as a placeholder, so that invalid pair will not be created.